# adsweb getting http 402 using TidHTTP

Tags: indy, delphi-xe6, advantage-database-server

I'm sometimes getting http 402 payment required when using TidHTTP accessing the Adsweb, but it is not on all computers. The same program run on one computer fine and on another I will get the 402 error running the same statement.

```
CSHttp: TidHTTP;

Try
    CSHttp := TidHTTP.Create(nil);
    MyURL := MasterTbl.FieldByName('DatabaseUrl').AsString;
    MyUrl := MyUrl + '__query?statement=select%20name,accountnum%20from%20customer%20where%20accountnum=''' + Myphone + '''&$format=json'
    with CSHttp do
         begin
              Request.CacheControl := 'no-cache';
              Request.BasicAuthentication := True;
              Request.Username := MasterTbl.FieldByName('DBlogin').AsString;
              Request.Password := MasterTbl.FieldByName('DBPassword').AsString;
              Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)';
         end;
    Try
    MyResult := CShttp.Get(MyURL);
    Except
         on E:Exception do
            Myerror := E.Message;

    End;
Finally
    CSHttp.Free;
end;
```

If I restart the ADS 11 it will sometimes fix it.
Maybe it is something do wrong in the call?
Thanks,
Kim

Comment: Sounds like something you should be discussing with Adsweb directly.

Comment: Unfortunately SAP the new owner of Advantage Database haven't answered any questions for years. I thought that maybe I wa missing some settings in my http call. I found when I get the error I would restart the Apache and it would work. I never had this error the one month we tested it on our own web server.